CONNECTION ERROR : WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket
I am getting following error while connecting with server in flutter.
Following is my connection code
 _socket=IO.io("http://localhost:3000/",
        OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .disableAutoConnect()  // disable auto-connection
            .build());

_print("CONNECTING......");
    if (_socket.connected) {
      _print("ALREADY CONNECTED TO SERVER");
      return;
    }
    _socket.connect();

    _socket.onConnect((_) {
      _print("CONNECTED TO SERVER");
      onConnected();

      // Listen for 'receive_message' event and add data to stream controller
      _socket.on('receive_message', (data) {
        _messageStreamController.add(MessageJson.fromJson(data).toDomain());
      });

    });


But when i call this connect method it gives me following error
CONNECTION ERROR : WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket
